# Is this considered bad practise in .Net Core MVC, when repeating code to do the same thing in dbcontext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dbcontext, dry

I have three classes, representing entities in the database.
They all have the same fields, and all which changes is their name, for example: DealerId and CompanyId.

I'm unsure of whether this is considered bad practice, but when I write my query to retrieve their information out the database, save to the database etc. I'm writing the same thing for each one, only ever changing the first word. eg. ****Id, ****Name.

Is there a better way of doing this? I know I could possibly use a dynamic object, but I'm not sure if this is also considered bad practice?

Here is a short example of some of the code which will be repeated.

```
public Companies GetCompany(int id)
    {
        Companies company = null;
        using (MySqlConnection connection = _GetConnection)
        {
            connection.Open();
            string query = "SELECT ddb_company_id, ddb_company_name FROM `ddb_companies` WHERE ddb_company_id = @Val1;";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Val1", id);
            command.Prepare();

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    company = new Companies
                    {
                        CompanyId = reader.GetInt32("ddb_company_id"),
                        CompanyName = reader.GetString("ddb_company_name"),
                        AddressValues = new AddressValues(),
                        FieldValues = new List<FieldValues>()
                    };
                }
            }
```

Comment: This kind of scenario doesn't violate the DRY concept as you are using these prefixes with the intend to name your properties. But you could instead remove the class name of the properties, this way you would ending with Id instead of CompanyId and Name insteaf of CompanyName. This makes your code cleaner and less verbose. Additionaly, is not possible to concatenate values to create a property name or variable.

Comment: You could have different approaches here, for example, only one class with an enum property identifying which type you have in fact, you also could have a base class with all common properties and derived ones with other names and/or properties. Both decreasing the verbosity of Id and Name as @Andre.Santarosa mentioned. Also if you keep the current approach, change the name of your class to Company, it represents much better a company than its plural. One last tip, since you're starting, use implicit declaration `var command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);` to improve readability.

Comment: Thank you, I have read before that I should be using var more. I guess I'm picking up bad habits already ;) . 
The naming of the classes and fields I have tried to match to the naming with the database, so the Companies class matches the companies table in the database, where companies would be plural as it lists more than one company. 
I believe perhaps having one base class could be what I'm looking for, one that handles the other three classes. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not bad practice - it's a matter of database design. It all depends on your needs, and why you came up with the namig that you did.
It could get hard to maintain though when the data set grows or if you have to rename fields.
One approach you can consider is using the name of the class properties in the sql query (which also implies renaming the fields in the db to match that). This would ensure that your code and your sql fields are in sync. The disadvantage is that renaming a propery in a class could break your application if you don't rename the db field too - so you have to be mindful about it.

you could rewrite your queries as:

```
 string query = $"SELECT "{nameof(CompanyId)}", "{nameof(CompanyName)}" FROM `ddb_companies` WHERE "{nameof(CompanyId)}" = @Val1;";
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe though your answer is more to do with naming and the query?
My main concern is that; My code above is one example of getting a company from the database, I will also have to get the dealer and subsidiary. 
The code is all the same, with only changing the class it relates to and the names used within. 
These are all using the same code, it is just the name which changes. Substituting the word company for dealers for example.
Not only is this making it a huge copy and paste job, but whenever I make an edit to one, I'm having to alter it in another two places.

Comment: I see - you can write a common method which takes a prefix as a parameter for convenience and it returns a data set that you can map to your object - however this is a dangerous approach which I wouldn't recommend unless you are certain your database structure wouldn't change. More code is not always bad because you can isolate individual cases and make sure the logic is separate - you have to always weigh that in vs saving lines of code.

Comment: That makes sense, and something I'll start taking into consideration (I'll probably have to learn the hard way a couple of times).
Thank you for your time to reply too.

Comment: No problem. I would appreciate an upvote if this is useful

Comment: Sorry, best I can do is add a tick.